# Remove rows which contain duplicate strings between the first 4 characters of two columns

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a large file that contains 4 columns and 7,000 lines. I need to remove the rows in which the start of the second column is the same as the start to the fourth column.

Input:

```
Gator_locus75   AATTCCATGTACG   Gator_locus23   CTAGAGGAAGT
Gator_locus18   AATTCCATTATGG   Gator_locus14   AATTCAAAAAAT
Gator_locus13   CTAGAACCCACC    Gator_locus72   CTAGAATGTATG
Gator_locus16   AATTCATCCTCT    Gator_locus15   CTAGATTGCCAA
Gator_locus24   CTAGAGCTGCTG    Gator_locus12   AATTCAGTCCAC
```

Output:

```
Gator_locus75   AATTCCATGTACG   Gator_locus23   CTAGAGGAAGT
Gator_locus16   AATTCATCCTCT    Gator_locus15   CTAGATTGCCAA
Gator_locus24   CTAGAGCTGCTG    Gator_locus12   AATTCAGTCCAC
```

I need to remove the rows in which the string the the second column starts "AATT" and the string in the same row fourth column starts "AATT". I also need to do the same thing when the string in the second column starts "CTAG" and the string in the fourth column starts "CTAG".

Comment: Is it only the first 4 characters of each that we should compare? Or did DopeGhoti interpret you correctly by literally comparing only AATT and CTAG?

Comment: Yes, only the first four characters of each should be compared. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. They both work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print lines where the first 4 characters of column 2 are not equal to the first 4 characters of column 4:

```
awk 'substr($2, 1, 4) != substr($4, 1, 4)' < input
```

This uses the main code as a "test" to see whether a line should be printed; there's no explicit action section, since the default-print action is what we want.  The main code simply extracts the first four characters from each column and compares them.

Answer (score 0):

To remove rows in which the second field starts with `AATT` *and* the fourth field starts with `AATT`, and the same with `CATG`:

```
awk '($2 !~ /^AATT/ && $4 !~ /^AATT/) && ($2 !~ /^CTAG/ && $4 !~ /^CTAG/) {print}' /path/to/file
```

As a more general solution:

```
awk 'substr($2,1,4) != substr($4,1,4) {print}' /path/to/file
```